# Setting a DIV in a specific place on a site with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a DIV on a specific are of my site, using this code:

```
<div style="position: fixed; left: 780px; right: 0; width:285px; z-index:9999; display:block; top:60px; color: #000; background-color:#fff; -webkit-border-radius:2px; -moz-border-radius:2px; border-radius:2px; box-shadow:0px 2px 5px #303030;">TEXT</div>
```

And it works well on my screen, because my screen resolution is 1240px width (The REMEMBER small notice is the DIV im trying to set):
[image: The REMEMBER small notice is the DIV im trying to set]

How ever, if I see the site on another computer with a different screen resolution, it changes the place where it is displayed, because it set 780px from the left.

Is there a way to set it up from the middle instead of the left (or right) margin?

Who can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide JS fiddle? Or link

Comment: You should avoid using `fixed` value but `absolute` instead. It seems you have an horizontal aligned container in your page. Try adding `position: relative` to the container and place your div having `TEXT` within the container, Then use absolute positioning to place that div properly.

Comment: have a look this http://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/GajhC?editors=110
maybe this strategy will work your scenario...

Comment: BTW if @EnterateNorte would post the markup and css and give some additional inforamtion like if he is able to change it or not or if he is using additional techniques/libraries like js/jQuery we would be able to help him a lot more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an easy way to positionate from the middle:

CSS:

```
#your-container {
 position: fixed or absolute
 left: 50%
 width: must have a fixed width (eg 250px)
 margin-left: -(width / 2) plus or minus offset (eg: -(250px / 2) for centered position or -(250px / 2) + 100px for position 100px to the right from the center)
}
```

PS This is just to answer your question but i would also tend to the suggestion of @Hashem Qolami given in his comment!

PPS [have a look this CODEPEN | maybe this strategy will work your scenario...](http://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/GajhC?editors=110)

hope it helps :)

Comment: Very nice. Specially if the header is also positioned as `fixed`.

Comment: D'accord @HashemQolami. One always have to troubleshoot in scenarios where the browsers width undergoes critical width-breakpoints.
But hey under special circumstances it CAN be a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to position the element below your language selection element, first be sure the language element is positioned explicitly (probably `position:relative`), make your "remember" element a child of the language element, then position it absolutely (looks like you're going for `right:0; bottom:20px` or something like that).

Answer (score 2):

looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. You have 2 options:

Modify your code:

```
<div style="position: fixed;  right: 20px /* or whatever you want */; width:285px; z-index:9999; display:block; top:60px; color: #000; background-color:#fff; -webkit-border-radius:2px; -moz-border-radius:2px; border-radius:2px; box-shadow:0px 2px 5px #303030;">TEXT</div>
```

be aware this way you'll have that box always showing, which could be good if the header is fixed, otherwise it will look horrible on scroll since it will show even if the nav isn't there.

The other approach (for example if you have a non fixed nav):

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 20px; width:285px; z-index:9999; display:block; top:60px; color: #000; background-color:#fff; -webkit-border-radius:2px; -moz-border-radius:2px; border-radius:2px; box-shadow:0px 2px 5px #303030;">TEXT</div>
```

Bottom line is you need to position the element FROM THE RIGHT instead of the left axis